# How much could honey-production be scaled up

Tags: economy, ecology, agriculture

[Worldwide 1,850,868 tonnes of honey is produced per year](https://www.atlasbig.com/en-us/countries-by-honey-production)

[There are eight species of bee that produce honey](https://bees4life.org/blog/curious-bee-life/8-honey-bee-species), it's not just apis mellifera.

Supposing honey became a main food source for humans, and farmers everywhere were highly motivated to maximise their honey production by whatever means they could. Supposing as much land currently given to rice was instead given to bee forage and [apiaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apiary).

Could honey production be scaled up 100-fold worldwide under these circumstances?

(synthetic honey is cheating; it has to be bees (or at least insects) for this scenario)

Comment: This is a math problem not worldbuilding.

Comment: No it's not. There's all kinds of ecological and economic implications.

Comment: Not with you've got it worded right now; at this stage you've said "if we turn over X amount of farmland to intensive honey production instead of cereal crops can the total production of honey be increased by Y amount?" given that statistics exist for the density at which you can intensively farm bees, we'll call that Z, this is then a math problem X x Z=A. A either is or is not equal to Y. Now if you want us to consider all the ecological and economic implications of this move *then* this is a book question and is Too Broad to be considered.

Comment: I guess I was relying on people to have the common sense that agriculture doesn't work that way. As they say in Jean de Florette: you can't breed rabbits by multiplying numbers on paper

Comment: I think it can be seen in the lens of math, but the original question seems more concerned with whether it is possible, and then secondarily what kind of impacts it would have. Personally it's difficult for me to answer that without knowing WHY we are switching to honey as a food source.

Comment: @ash Calculating planet orbits is just math, but we do it regularly for questions. Such questions are definitely valid for WB. It’s a hypothetical to establish plausibility of a created world.

Comment: @SRM Orbits are not A times B equals C they're hideously complex dynamic equations with variables that the person asking the question is rarely even aware of. This question lays out a finished equation and asks us to solve it.

Comment: @Ash So it isn't a hard question; that doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: @SRM It's a "please use Google for me, I can't be bothered doing my own research" question.

Comment: @ash no, it isn’t a quick Google search, and even if it was, such questions are still legit — explicitly — under Stack Exchange rules. Plenty of StackOverflow questions are answered by directly quoting online manuals. Bee optimization is a bit beyond even that.

Comment: @SRM Why then do I routinely see people get panned for lack of research?

Comment: @Ash Because plenty of people take your attitude and presume laziness, but Stack Exchange officially takes the tack that most people do try Google/Bing/etc first and if they're asking, there's a reason they're asking. They may be a kid, they may be way outside their typical knowledge domain such that even basic searches fail with the keywords they choose, etc. Answer now, and if you can supplement your answer with info to help them search in the future, so much the better. You can even vote the question down, but not close it.

Comment: @SRM Yeah I answered yesterday, with two minutes worth of Google and a calculator, and withdrew my close vote, when you said it wasn't a bad question. I did want some clarification though, I'm back online after a considerable hiatus and the site rules, written and unwritten, shift in my absence.

Comment: @Ash "get panned for lack of research?" Because they are and on top of that they bring trash in the house, like that hard science question about chemistry of plants which break all laws of thermodynamics, and broke perpetuum mobile along the way before it landed on wb. This one question is interesting enough, starting that it needs 1000 fold increase, it should not be one kind of plants, arable land is not only or one to to look at. And in genral it needs a good nay-answer(probably, most likely), but bees are the best and sure they need help, 10x would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

So my dad is an avid bee keeper and keeps a couple of hives. From my understanding bees can fly a pretty good distance, like several miles, so a bee farm in a rural area I don't think will have much problems supporting that kind of large bee population.

But if you were doing it in a more urban environment you would need to have flowering plants for them to pollinate. In that sense it gives you an excuse (as if you *needed one* ) to grow produce that flowers, or just flowers in general.

I'm not sure what other resources bees need to survive, but I don't see anything stopping you necessarily.

One thing of note however is how the populations of pollinating creatures is decreasing worldwide, why, we do not exactly know. I think it probably has more to do with climate change and other environmental impacts than high volume bee keeping though.

I'd recommend  looking up the process for how honey is made on an industrial scale. That will probably give you some additional info as to details on the honey would be harvested.

In summation I think it is theoretically possible. I'm sure you'd run into some kind of issues though. This is also highly dependent on what the circumstances pushing us to do this are. Is this in the future? Post apocalypse? The past? etc.

You would need a really, really good reason for humans to switch from our wonderful vegetables, fruits and grains (and the not so good stuff for us) to exclusively, or mostly honey. Humans like our food. It has been a constant throughout civilization that we will go to great lengths to do things like getting spices.

If you were to place so much emphasis on honey as a food source you'd want to also think about ways that the honey could be prepared differently.

Comment: You know, I'm something of a ~~scientist~~, beekeeper myself. Apis mellifera will fly commonly about a mile for water and nectar, five miles if they really have to. If you've provided enough bee-forage in a mile radius, they won't go further. Note that you wouldn't replace fruit in OP's scenario: you'd grow more fruit because most fruit is bee-forage.

Comment: On another note, there is somewhat of a trend of people planting bee-friendly plants in their garden or even sprinkling seeds of local wildflower seeds in unkempt patches of ground / grass, and urban bee farms (rather small scale, but still)

Comment: According [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Northern_American_nectar_sources_for_honey_bees) you could plant trees, not only flowers

Answer (score 4):

As of 2019 there were, best estimate, [162 million-ish Hectares of farmland growing rice worldwide](https://www.statista.com/statistics/271969/world-rice-acreage-since-2008/). On land specifically planted for intensive bee raising you can put [3 to 5 hives per Hectare](https://www2.gnb.ca/content/gnb/en/departments/10/agriculture/content/bees/managing.html). Each hive will produce an average of [~20kg of Honey](https://beekeepinginsider.com/how-much-honey-does-a-hive-produce/) per year.

So if you could plant the world's rice patties in high density bee food, not a given, you might, theoretically, produce an average of 16,206,000 additional tonnes of honey per year, not quite a 10 fold increase.

To get to a hundred times our current production you'd need to use 1.85 billion Hectares of land for nothing but raising bees at maximum density. Unfortunately there are only 1.407 billion Hectares of [arable land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arable_land) on earth so it probably can't be done.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the number of bees, but the amount of land required to grow the flowers which will provide the nectar for the bees. Actually the problem is the same as the problem of farming animals for food. The efficiency from the productivity of the land to the animal processing and up to the end product. Since only a tiny part of the plant will be used to make the honey I suspect that the whole process is even less efficient than cattle farming which requires huge amounts of land to produce the grains and the soya that will end up in the fodder.

The only way to expand at a reasonable cost the current production would be to use unused land. But since you want a huge production simply growing wild flower plants would not be enough. You have two options:

- find a way to grow trees that produce a lot of flowers in semi desert areas, so you'll have to find a way to bring a lot of water there. The only solution would be pumping there sewage that would be otherwise thrown away.
- build huge underground hydroponic farms. If you build them far North you would have plenty of water, otherwise water would still be a problem, but there would be much less evaporation.

However even with all the efforts a 100-fold increase would be very difficult. Chances are that the economy will push towards the option that you discarded. Making synthetic honey from sugars.

Comment: bee can harvest not only flowers but trees (like apple tree, linden tree etc) too. Even more: they could collect sugar/sirup and make honey from it

Comment: @ADS they do not make honey from sugar sirup, they handle it same way as nectar, which (fructose and all that stuff) makes honey after a bit of fermenting and water evaporation inside hive. But they do not convert or synthesise stuff. So honey mixed with sugar(or be mostly sugar) has no sense and is just crap(there is no other word for it, it is like that). But yes they are like wasps - keen on robbing what they can rob for sweets(other bee hives included) - there are funny stories like they found candy factory or something like that, and owner had all kinds of colors in his not so much honey.

Comment: Out of trees Lindens is the best, but it not possible to have one kind of plant to cover everything, because every plant has specific period of when they have flowers. It has to be many plants which flower at different time and bees collect from them

Answer (score 1):

Bees [can convert](https://www.honeybeesuite.com/rebuttal-bees-turn-sugar-into-honey/) <s>sugar</s> siroup (sweetened water) to the honey. I suppose plants (of trees and flowers combined together) is still essential but you could increase honey output at cost of it quality. Since I'm not a beekeeper I can't estimate how many additional honey you could get by that way.

Comment: Good link, but yeah it requires some clarifications, which are irrelevant for op. What is relevant is that sugar better be used directly, it a waste of sugar and energy to give it to bees in that scaleup situation. As exchange sugar for honey - yeah it is a good trade. As partial breakdown of it with help of bees - yean it questionable stuff, we can do that better on industrial scale. But link is a good one, cheers.

Comment: And yes, I probanly was a bit rusty and extreame in the other comment. It just by expirience you can taste the difference by solubility when people try to fake honey with sugar adding(or it could be from hives but I can't know or confirm how exactly it was made - so those impressions I had with honey which is already in jars - had some not so great expirience few times - made my other comment a bit more extreame than it should be), I just do not recall, and probably didn't tasted one from beehive which was made by bees out of sugar, hm, need to test/taste it.

Comment: @MolbOrg Yep, that's why I added 'at cost of quality' :) I suppose when quantity is target (as in original question) - then quality is no matters. And of course, some would eat 101% pure honey - just for additional price.